# Parallel processing options in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, parallel-processing

I recently created a python script that performed some natural language processing tasks and worked quite well in solving my problem. But it took 9 hours. I first investigated using hadoop to break the problem down into steps and hopefully take advantage of the scalable parallel processing I'd get by using Amazon Web Services.

But a friend of mine pointed out the fact that Hadoop is really for large amounts of data store on disk, for which you want to perform many simple operations. In my situation I have a comparatively small initial data set (low 100s of Mbs) on which I perform many complex operations, taking up a lot of memory during the process, and taking many hours.

What framework can I use in my script to take advantage of scalable clusters on AWS (or similar services)?

Answer (score 0):

[Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/) is one option for distributing things over multiple machines in a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/parallel-mapreduce-in-python/) shows how to do a MapReduce like script, using processes on a single machine. Secondly, if you can, try caching intermediate results. I did this for a NLP task and obtained a significant speed up.

Answer (score 0):

My package, [jug](http://luispedro.org/software/jug), might be very appropriate for your needs. Without more information, I can't really say how the code would look like, but I designed it for sub-hadoop sized problems.

Comment: I gave it a quick read - is jug more like Celery or more like Hadoop? What problem does jug solve that they don't?

Comment: More like celery, but it has a different sort of flavour. It has less overhead than Hadoop (but it cannot scale as well).